# Get id of link when id is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a bunch of stuff in it. I also have a link inside that div, which has a dynamically generated id. There's no way to tell what the id will be.

When I click that link, how can I get the id of that link into a variable jQuery? In a *.js file?

Comment: Can you uniquely identify the `<div>` and does it have only the one link inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**With Tag Name**

```
$('a').click(function(){
 //alert($(this).attr('id');  
 alert(this.id); //Better then the statement above as it is javascript with jQuery wrapper
});
```

**With class**

```
$('.classOfAnchor').click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id');
 alert(this.id);  //Better then the statement above as it is javascript with jQuery wrapper
});
```

Comment: Or just `this.id` and save yourself two unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    //alert( $(this).attr('id') );
     alert(this.id); //Better then above
});
```

Comment: If he doesn't know what the ID of the link is, how is he supposed to bind an event handler to it using an ID selector?

Answer (score 0):

Unless something gives the element an id, there won't be one.

But, for the sake of explanation, lets say there definitely is an ID on that link..

if you were using jQuery, you could simply select its container div and then traverse down to the link: `var myID = $('div#theContainingDiv').children('a').attr('id');`

or, you can just do what the other people said to do -- that will work too.